# PHP reference variable by case-insensitive string

Tags: php

PHP 5.  I'm in a situation where I need to translate a case-insensitive url query to member variables in a PHP object.  Basically, I need to know what member variable the url query key points to so I can know if it's numeric or not.

For example:

```
class Foo{
    $Str;
    $Num;
}

myurl.com/stuff?$var=value&num=1
```

When processing this URL query, I need to know that "str" associates with Foo->$Str, etc.  Any ideas on how to approach this?  I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
function fooHasProperty($foo, $name) {
  $name = strtolower($name);
  foreach ($foo as $prop => $val) {
    if (strtolower($prop) == $name) {
      return $prop;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}

$foo = new Foo;

// Loop through all of the variables passed via the URL
foreach ($_GET as $index => $value) {
  // Check if the object has a property matching the name of the variable passed in the URL
  $prop = fooHasProperty($foo, $index);
  // Object property exists already
  if ($prop !== FALSE) {
    $foo->{$prop} = $value;
  }
}
```

And it may help to take a look at php's documentation on [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

**Example:**

URL: myurl.com/stuff?var=value&num=1

Then `$_GET` looks like this:

```
array('var' => 'value', 'num' => '1')
```

Looping through that, we would be checking if `$foo` has a property `var`, (`$foo->var`) and if it has a property `num` (`$foo->num`).

Comment: interesting, this would work case-insensitive?  So it would set $foo->Var (capital V) when the query looks like the one you posted?

Comment: If you need it to be case insensitive, you can always use php's [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) assuming everything is lowercase. For example: `$index = strtolower($index); $foo->{$index}`. @user2177707 - Do your object properties follow a naming convention? Like all lowercase except the first letter, all uppercase, etc?

Comment: CamelCase, which makes it hard to determine the format automatically (hence my despair. :) ).

Comment: @user2177707 - Please see my revised answer. Though not super efficient, this will work for finding out if a property exists in your object. This will **not** work if you have two properties that evaluate to the same lowercase string: e.g. `CamelCase` and `CAMELcase`, but that would be a poor design strategy anyways.